# Convertir String a Bytes y Bytes a Imagen Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Estoy usando Visual basic

Tengo la siguiente funcion que me recibe una imagen en string en la variable "imagenremito", luego debe transformarse el string en un arreglo de bytes y almacenarlo en la variable "imagenenbytes" despues este debe transformase en una imagen y almacenarlo en la variable Imagenreducida. El error se produce cuando quiero ejecutar "Imagenreducida = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)" me dice que "el parametro no es valido" "'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.ArgumentException' al tipo 'Entidades.Excepcion", como puedo pasar la imagen en bytes a Image?

```
Public Shared Function registrarremitosconfoto(ByVal vac_id As Integer, ByVal id_remito As Integer, ByVal fecharemito As String, ByVal idproveedor As Integer, ByVal tipocombustible As Integer, ByVal litroscargados As Double, ByVal montototal As Double, ByVal imagenremito As String) As String

    Dim imagenenbytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagenremito)

    Dim Imagenreducida As Image
    If imagenenbytes.Length > 10 ^ 6 Then
        Imagenreducida = comprobartamano(imagenenbytes)
    Else
        Imagenreducida = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)
    End If

    Try

        Dim remito As String = RemitoDatos.registrarremitosconfoto(vac_id, id_remito, fecharemito, idproveedor, tipocombustible, litroscargados, montototal, New ImageConverter().ConvertTo(Imagenreducida, GetType(Byte())))

        Return remito
    Catch ex As Entidades.Excepcion
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Te proporciono un código que usé con éxito con Visual Basic en el que tomaba el archivo de imagen y lo convertía en una matriz de bytes. Esa matriz de bytes era lo que me aceptaba iTextSharp como imagen. No sé si puede servirte ver mi función **Tomar_BytesArchivo**. En mi caso uso **IO.File.ReadAllBytes** para tomar los Bytes.

Supongo que el problema en tu código es porque estás intentando convertir la matriz de bytes en *Imagen* y probablemente no sea posible. ¿Lo has comprobado?

```
Dim jpg As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Tomar_BytesArchivo(Server.MapPath("~") & "\Imagenes\logocpm1edit.jpg"))

Public Function Tomar_BytesArchivo(ByVal ruta As String) As Byte()
     'convierto en unamatriz de bytes 
      Return IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta)
End Function
```